# How to call setTimeout after an HTTP request in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a call to reserveStock endpoint and after a certain interval I need to call releaseStock endpoint, I tried  two approaches: one is to add a tap side effect in the http call and another is to call it inside a subscribe function, both codes didn't run.

```js
reserveStock() {
    return combineLatest([
      this.getActiveCartId().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()),
      this.authService.getOccUserId().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()),
    ])
      .pipe(
        switchMap(([cartId, userId]) => {

          const api = this.OCC.getUrl(configURL, {
            cartId: cartId,
            userId: userId,
          });

          return this.http.post(api, {})
        })
      )
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log('res', res)
        if (this.releaseStockTimeout) {
          clearTimeout(this.releaseStockTimeout);
        } 
        this.releaseStockTimeout = this.setReleaseStockTimeout();
      });
  }

releaseStock() {
    return combineLatest([
      this.getActiveCartId().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()),
      this.authService.getOccUserId().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()),
    ])
      .pipe(
        switchMap(([cartId, userId]) => {

          const api = this.OCC.getUrl(configURL, {
            cartId: cartId,
            userId: userId,
          });

          return this.http.post(api, {});
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

setReleaseStockTimeout() {
    console.log('setReleaseStockTimeout')
    
    return setTimeout(() => {
      this.releaseStock();
    }, 20000);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "releaseStock endpoint"?? something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72568848/1657465)?

Also, it would be great to see a stackblitz example?

Comment: Have you considered building the "Release" portion of this into server code? If someone closes the webpage after reserving stock, you might find yourself with incorrectly locked stock

Answer (score 2):

Here I have used a delay to switchMap to the release call. I mapped the response to the cart and userId to for the release call. Then there is a cancel subject. If you make cancel$ emit before the delay triggers it will complete the observable so the call to release doesn't happen.

```
cancel$ = new Subject<void>();

reserveStock() {
    return combineLatest([
      this.getActiveCartId().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()),
      this.authService.getOccUserId().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()),
    ])
      .pipe(
        switchMap(([cartId, userId]) => {

          const api = this.OCC.getUrl(configURL, {
            cartId: cartId,
            userId: userId,
          });

          return this.http.post(api, {}).pipe(map(() => [cartId, userId]))
        }),
        delay(20000),
        switchMap(([cartId, userId]) => {

          const api = this.OCC.getUrl(configURL, {
            cartId: cartId,
            userId: userId,
          });

          return this.http.post(api, {});
        }),
        takeUntil(cancel$)
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

cancel() {
  this.cancel$.next();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes,we can achieve this by using **setTimeOut** to call your 'releaseStock' endpoint after some interval, please refer below :

```
reserveStock() {
    return combineLatest([
      this.getActiveCartId().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()),
      this.authService.getOccUserId().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()),
    ])
      .pipe(
        switchMap(([cartId, userId]) => {

          const api = this.OCC.getUrl(configURL, {
            cartId: cartId,
            userId: userId,
          });

          return this.http.post(api, {})
        })
      )
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log('res', res)
        if (this.releaseStockTimeout) {
          clearTimeout(this.releaseStockTimeout);
        } 
        this.releaseStockTimeout = this.setReleaseStockTimeout();
      });
  }

releaseStock() {
    return combineLatest([
      this.getActiveCartId().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()),
      this.authService.getOccUserId().pipe(distinctUntilChanged()),
    ])
      .pipe(
        switchMap(([cartId, userId]) => {

          const api = this.OCC.getUrl(configURL, {
            cartId: cartId,
            userId: userId,
          });

          return this.http.post(api,{});
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Then you have use **setTimeOut** to call your *releaseStock* endpoint after certain interval as below,

```
setTimeOut (()=>{
  this.releaseStock() // This will be called after 3 seconds timeout. 
},3000);
```